# Why is VS Code not showing errors in C# (Unity)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, visual-studio-code

I'm using VS Code and Unity, and I noticed that errors are showing on Unity console but not the VS Code, I looked up and did everything that this page says and nothing worked: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

Is there a fix to this?

Comment: Have you properly setup VS code with unity? Follow this guide https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity to make sure.

Comment: @MrMoonMan As I said above I did everything there already and the errors are still not showing for C#

Comment: Just a wildshot here, but are you maybe trying to install a debugger? https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Unity.unity-debug

Comment: @dekuShrub I have it installed however I cannot select it as a Debugger. In the extension page I read that if it doesn't appear I need to delete the "launch.json" file but I did it and it still doesn't show up. Do you know if there's a way I can manually add it as a configuration to the file? That would fix it for sure.

Comment: @JoãoSilva it is explained in the link I added in my previous comment. I'm guessing that you can just copy that configuration if you adjust the version number to match your installed debugger.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem too. One day Code's errors were connected, the next day, they had disappeared. Most frustrating. This worked for me:-

1. Install the latest .net SDK from here [DotNet SDK download](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download)

2) Regenerate project files from Edit->Preferences->External Tools

Note: just regenerating the project files didn't work for me. Needed DotNet SDK update.

Answer (score 2):

The official doc is wrong https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/other/unity

step 5 : In the VS Code Settings editor (Ctrl+,), uncheck the C# extension's Omnisharp: Use Modern Net setting ("omnisharp.useModernNet": false)

You need to do the exact opposite and check it.